# Vue.js validator evaluate old value on v-model when changed by javascript instead of typing

Tags: validation, vue.js

I am now getting trouble by the following code.

```
<input type="text" v-validate:startdate="['required']" v-model="current.start_at">
<date-picker :model.sync="current.start_at"></date-picker>
```

The problem is that the required validation works with the old value instead of new value of **current.start_at** when I change start_at on date-picker.

So, for example, instead of 01/01/2001, it still keeps 01/01/200 when validate with required, so it makes me mad.

I hope to get a solution about it.

Please help me!